# Obtaining the height of Explorer's items view header

Tags: c++, winapi, explorer, getsystemmetrics

I was wondering if there's a system metric for the height of Explorer's items view header, or if there's a simple way of obtaining that value.

My current approach is to obtain the header's `IUIAutomationElement`. Then I get the element's bounding rectangle, and then I get the height. But I was wondering if there was a simpler way that doesn't involve IUIAutomation. Thank you for any info.

Comment: There is no requirement that Explorer's items view have a header at all. For example, switch into Large Icon mode.

Comment: Yes, that's my bad.